# Removing characters and moving a flat file using T-Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please can someone assist as I have not managed to find an answer anywhere? My issue is that I have an ERP system which I need to import the same file (DDLS1GST.DAT) into each day. I know how to add the date for example when moving a file but do not know how to remove such information from the file name and then move it to the specific location.

The file I receive from a third party is named 'example_sales_20131120.prn' and I need to trim this, rename it and move it as 'DDL1GST.DAT' to the necessary location.

In theory all I need to do is instruct sequel to look for a file name like '%example...' but I have no idea how to do that.

```
declare 
@cmdstring varchar(1000),
@testname varchar(50)

set @testname = 'DDL1GST'+ '.DAT'

set @cmdstring = 'move /Y \\Server\Data\User\ExampleFiles\Old\%example... \\Server\Data\User\ExampleFiles\' + @testname
print @cmdstring
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstring
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out with some assistance using the below:

```
declare 
@cmdstring varchar(1000),
@testname varchar(50),
@date varchar(20)

set @date = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 103), '/', '')
set @testname = 'DDL1GST'+'.DAT' 
print @testname
set @cmdstring = 'move /Y \\Server\Data\User\Sales\Sql\example_sales_'+ @date+'.prn \\Server\Data\User\Sales\' + @testname

print @cmdstring
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstring
```